# Java Criteria Query with Hibernate - generated alias invalid path?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, predicate, hibernate-criteria

I have the following `java` code that uses `hibernate` predicates to return search reusults from my Appointment `MYSQL` table.

```
public List<Appointment> getSearchResults(String client, AppointmentSearchRequest searchRequest, Predicate completePredicate) {

    List<Appointment> searchResults = new ArrayList<>();
    EntityManager entityManager = null;

    try {
        entityManager = entityManagement.createEntityManager(client);
        CriteriaBuilder builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<Appointment> query = builder.createQuery(Appointment.class);
        Root<Appointment> from = query.from(Appointment.class);
        CriteriaQuery<Appointment> selectQuery = query.select(from);
        selectQuery = selectQuery.where(completePredicate);

        searchResults = entityManager.createQuery(selectQuery).setFirstResult(searchRequest.getIndex()).setMaxResults(searchRequest.getSize()).getResultList();
    }catch (Exception e){
       //
    }

    return searchResults;
}
```

When I run this code, at the following line:

```
searchResults = entityManager.createQuery(selectQuery).setFirstResult(searchRequest.getIndex()).setMaxResults(searchRequest.getSize()).getResultList();
```

I am getting the error:

```
17:20:27,730 ERROR [org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter] (http-/127.0.0.1:8080-2) Invalid path: 'generatedAlias1.title'
17:20:27,734 ERROR [org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter] (http-/127.0.0.1:8080-2) Invalid path: 'generatedAlias1.title':  Invalid path: 'generatedAlias1.title'
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.LiteralProcessor.lookupConstant(LiteralProcessor.java:119) [hibernate-core-4.2.7.SP1-redhat-3.jar:4.2.7.SP1-redhat-3]
```

What could be causing this error?

Comment: You can try updating your hibernate version and check, this will help

Comment: this has not worked

Comment: The latest version is Hibernate 5.4.x. Which version did you try?

Comment: I think the problem is the predicates are created by different CriteriaBuilder (different alias)

Comment: Can you please expand on this in an answer? Thanks

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60551105/using-the-same-predicates-for-two-criteria-queries

Comment: Ah I see, so I need to create the predicate with the same criteria builder as I get the results with?

Comment: Yes, the problem is the root with which the predicate is being created, you must make sure that it is the same as the one used in the query. Maybe the best opction is create de predicate inside the `getSearchResults` and rewrite the method to take the conditions in another way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ironically i just had exactly the same issue some days ago: the problem is your path "generatedAlias1.title" which is understandable in JPQL as a dereference of the field *title* from an inner entity referenced with *generatedAlias1*.

Unluckily this complex path in a single String cannot be understood by the *CriteriaBuilder*.

This path is normally described within the Predicate element which you are passing here as an argument to your method *getSearchResults* with name *completePredicate* ... ( the problem is that you did not tell us how you are creating this predicate )

So you need to refactor the way in which you declare this path, eventually using the class javax.persistence.criteria.Path and calculating it with this method

```
final private <V> Path<V> getPath(Root<T> root, String attributeName) {
        Path<V> path = null;
        for (String part : attributeName.split("\\.")) {
            path = (path == null) ? root.get(part) : path.get(part);
        }
        return path;
}
```

Where you will pass the property *from* of your method *getSearchResults* as the argument *root*, and the string containing "generatedAlias1.title" as *attributeName*; then you can re-declare your predicate as an instance of Predicate which is acting on this path here returned.

I hope I have been clear enough

Answer (score 0):

## Try checking your Query

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39011179/11500542). It might be just as simple as checking your query aliases. Make sure that they match, otherwise the query won't compile at all. You didn't list your full query here, so I can't tell if it's incorrect or not.